# VBA localization effort 1004 assign formula to cell

Tags: excel, vba, localization

Using the following code

Where unit_amount is 2 for example.

class1

```
Dim INCOME_ROW As Integer

Private Sub Class_Initialize()   
    INCOME_ROW = 4   
End Sub

Sub calculate_total(unit_amount)
    Dim total As Range
    With sht_income
        .Cells(INCOME_ROW, 9).Value = "Total"
        Set total = .Cells(INCOME_ROW, 10)
    End With
    
    StartRw = INCOME_ROW - unit_amount
    EndRw = INCOME_ROW - 1
    
    sum_formula = "(R" & StartRw & "C:R" & EndRw & "C)"
    total.Formula2R1C1 = "=SUM" & sum_formula & ""
    
    INCOME_ROW = INCOME_ROW + 1
End Sub
```

So the formula to be pasted is going to be `=SUM(R2C:R3C)` for example

This leads on one specific system (with Dutch locale) to a 1004 error (in English Application-defined or Object-defined error)

[image: 1004 Application-defined or Object-defined error]

However i've tested this sheet with us-en and nl settings using the following possibilities which all work on my and another users system.

- Windows 11 EN and Excel NL
- Windows 11 NL and Excel NL
- Windows 11 EN and Excel EN

I've seen solution suggesting using different seperators `,` instead of `;` solving the issue for some users. However in this case I don't use any seperator.

Perhaps I should parse the formula differently?

Any advice how to troubleshoot this - probably localization - error?

Comment: with INCOME_ROW = 2 and unit_amount= 2 that makes StartRw  0.  There is no row 0. your string ends up being `=SUM(R0C:R1C)`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification question. In another part of the code the `INCOME_ROW` is updated to 4 before this specific issue is raised. But to make the question code simple I have adjusted the value during `Class_Initialize()`. *Which by the way does not break the program in my enviroment.*

Comment: When it breaks and highlights the line that is in error, what are the values of the two variables.  And does the value in `sum_formula` make sense.  You will need to provide a little more information.

Comment: And since you simplified the code. Does this simplified code still cause the same error?

Comment: Does the dutch system have the same excel version as you?

Comment: change total.Formula2R1C1   to  total.FormulaR1C1

Comment: @ΑΓΡΙΑΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ is right. Properties like `Formula2` are available only in recent Excel versiona so if your version is older, just remove the `2`

Comment: Although the user did had Windows 11  I assumed `Formula2` would work. As I use this since Windows 10. I'll create a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by commentars. It had probably to do with `Formula2`. Changing it to `Formula` resolved the issue.

Note: Meanwhile the client updated their machine to Windows 11 22H2 with the *recieve updates from other Microsoft products* checked. [image: Windows advanced options]

This could have updated their Excel version as well. Unfortunately no check to determine if `Formula` was the only thing necessary. Also did not check if `Formula2` worked in the new situation. Something to check next time.

Thanks for the help